# Sharing screen with Messages.app on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, messages, screen-sharing, firewall

Both computers are running OS X 10.8.4

When trying to initiate the screen sharing feature, the other computer gets the request, then clicks "Accept" but thats as far as we get.

Then we see this:
[image]

I have posted the contents of the "Details" section:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yWYYCbgv

I am thinking we may need to open some ports on the firewall. Anyone know which ports need to be open? Or if this is even the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening up port 5222 (for iChat/Messages).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Thecafremo The question is "Anyone know which ports need to be open" and the answer listed here (albeit not really in an authoritative manner) is port 5222. I don't see how that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Edited for more authoritativeness. :-)

Comment: @tubedogg That edit makes quite a difference. :)